# HP ESXi WBEM Agent Not Showing Power Supply Data

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esxi, hardware, hp, hp-proliant

Server: HP ProLiant DL 380 G5
ESXi: 5.0.0 U1 (HP Custom Image)
HP SIM: 7.1 (CentOS 6.3 VM)

I have my basic hardware monitoring up and running. I cannot see events for power supply failure within HP SIM but I can see the event within the vSphere client.

The vSphere client shows everything I can think of correctly, Processors, Storage, Temperature, Fan, Software Components and Power.

The HP SIM shows under status: MPs (iLo), Network, Physical Memory, Processors, Sensors (if you click on it it times out and says no data in the table is available), Smart Array.

The HP SIM shows under configuration: Firmware and Software, MPs, Network, PCI Devices (if you click on it it times out and says no data in the table is available), Physical Memory, Processors, Sensors (this works and displays fan speed and other temperature information, why does this not show in status?), Smart Array

What will make my HP SIM recognize the additional monitoring indicators that are obviously available?

This I have tried:
- Restarting the CIM Services on the ESXi host
- Restarting the HP SIM Server
- Deleting and Re-adding the DL 380 G5 from and to the HP SIM
- Completely rebuilding the HP SIM

Side-note: When referencing the WBEM information I have noticed it takes roughly 20 seconds for each hardware component to be queried and it just sits there saying "Collecting Data". Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

After several days in production without restarting or changing anything the remaining missing WBEM data began showing up.

All in all I'm disappointed at the speed that WBEM queries return. I have seen this now in 3 HP hosts I setup this way.

I also noticed that after installing the HP tools you will get vCenter information for all the things that HP SIM gives you so if you wanted you could monitor it there instead of implementing another solution.